# Kinect shows only grayscale images instead of colored one

Tags: kinect, ros

I have very weird problem and haven't found any answer yet, so maybe someone here ever saw smth like this?

When I start NiViewer demo, it works and shows depth image on the left, but grayscale image on the right. 
When I start Sample-NiSimpleViewer demo it won't work and gives error 
The device image format must be RGB24

The weirdest thing is that about 2 weeks ago everything was fine - no errors and image was coloured.

I think changes occurred after installing ROS packages for openni or maybe I made some damage in settings(however I am very inexperienced user, I don't recollect changing anything anywhere).

I thought that maybe kinect is broken, but when I start it from under ROS (rviz or image_view) it actually shows coloured image.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried openni_launch with RVIZ !? RViz can also visualize RGB images / point clouds.